# How to show the App bar above the drawer drawer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I am trying to develop a flutter app in which I want the navigation drawer to display below the app bar and I also want to change the icon of the drawer once the user clicks it.

Comment: sorry i am unable to post codes here because stack overflow restrict me to post the code by saying format error and i don't know how post my in specified format asked by stack over flow ,that is why i dint posted my code here but i desperately in need of help please help me with this guys.

Comment: You can post the code as text. Someone might format it for you.

Comment: how do you want to change the icon ? like its color or the icon itself

Comment: Removed thanks and all, and corrected grammar.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the drawer shows above the whole UI (hiding the app bar) and this is what [Material Design specs](https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html) tell as well. But if you really want to achieve this, you can have similar effect by using the code below:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Body'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: demo]